# Working with Android Studio and Epson TM

Tags: android, printing, epson

A few days ago I made an application Itext, now I see that created pdfs not print well, I saw about EPSON POS SDK for Android, could explain how to work with that?
Now i have big problem cause i cant add table like ITEXT someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Manual is there where you can find programming guide.

https://thepapertreeacademy.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/epos-print_sdk_android_e_reva.pdf

Comment: I have a question, I have to send the PDF to the SDK or create the invoice with this SDK? Thx for help Dharmaraj.

Comment: First go through docs where your all grievence will be resolved. In this option is there to select a file to print.

Comment: This SDK is something like iText right? I see something similar has Itext, sorry if I upset a lot, is my first time with Epson Printers...

Comment: iText is for generating PDF file,whereas EPSON POS SDK for Android is for printing purpose.

Comment: I see, then to create and print an invoice would be with the SDK, itext stay out?

Comment: I think im doing fine creating ticket, now i have a big problem with this SDK  can i print a table?